# jQuery addClass() to ul:nth-child?

Tags: javascript, jquery, addclass, css-selectors

I'm unable to addClass() using the following code:

```
    var width = $('.pane').width();
    var column_index = $('#home-container div ul.hub').index('#home-container div ul');
    var column_counter = column_index + 1;

    $('#home-container div ul:nth-child(' + column_counter + ')').next().addClass('hub');

    $('#home-container').animate({"left": -width*column_counter}, 300);
```

Here's the [EXAMPLE](http://www.justinbillmeier.com/testing/)

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain what's happening?  Just saying that it doesn't work makes it very hard to see where the issue is.  What does happen?  Do you get errors on the console?

Comment: The problem is that the class just doesn't get added. There are no errors in the console.

Comment: A couple problems so I've made several edits, but I finally got 'em all fixed. Check my answer again. You'll find a complete set of working code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is three part (primarily relating to your use of `index()`).

Firstly, `index()` accepts an element `$('#el')`, not a selector `'#el'` ...

Secondly, you're saying, "Get all `<ul class="hub">`s, then tell me what the index is of the first `<ul>` ... well, that'll always be 1.

What you mean is, get all `<ul>`s then show me the index of `<ul class="hub">`.

Short version? Replace your second line with this one ...

```
var column_index = $('#home-container div ul').index( $('#home-container div ul.hub') );
```

... however, for the rest of your code to work you need to remove the `class="hub"` from the previous element, and add it to the current one. So replace your fourth line with these ...

```
$('#home-container > div:nth-child(' + column_counter + ') > ul').removeClass('hub');
$('#home-container > div:nth-child(' + (column_counter+1) + ') > ul').addClass('hub');
```

... or even easier, replace your entire code set with this ...

```
var width = $('.pane').width();
var column_index = $('#home-container div ul').index( $('#home-container div ul.hub') );
var column_counter = column_index + 1;

$('#home-container > div:nth-child(' + column_counter + ') > ul').removeClass('hub');
$('#home-container > div:nth-child(' + (column_counter+1) + ') > ul').addClass('hub');

$('#home-container').animate({"left": -width*column_counter}, 300);
```

Just tested this on your site, so it should work for you.

Comment: This was exactly the solution I needed. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

this `var column_index = $('#home-container div ul.hub').index('#home-container div ul');`
needs to be this `var column_index = $('#home-container > div > ul.hub').index('#home-container > div > ul');`

same with the others. if something  is a child of something to show that as a selector use the greater than symbol ">"

Answer (score 0):

`next()` method gets the immediately following sibling of each element in the set of matched elements. If a selector is provided, it retrieves the next sibling only if it matches that selector.

In your case `$('#home-container div ul:nth-child(' + column_counter + ')').next()`  will result in an empty set because there is no sibling to this ul which you selected. Also `nth-child` selector will not help you in this case. Try this.

```
var width = $('.pane').width();
var column_index = $('#home-container div ul.hub')
                   .index('#home-container div ul');
var column_counter = column_index + 1;

$('#home-container div ul').eq(column_counter).addClass('hub');
```